# How to access command line variables from the code using npm script in webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I need to access command line parameters from npm script in my "constants.js" file.

I found I can access parameters in webpack.config.js file with process.env, but it is undefined in app source files.

I need to run the script from the console, for example:

```
npm webpack-dev-server --hot MY_PARAMETER=some_value
```

And then access MY_PARAMETER in my constants.js somehow, for example with:

```
process.env.MY_PARAMETER === "some_value"   // true
```

Can somebody help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.env` file, your best bet will be to use [`dotenv-webpack`](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack) (and optionally, [`string-replace-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) or something similar). Reading the documentation, as a suggestion, you'll probably want to add a `.env.local` entry to your VCS ignore file (`.gitignore`, `.hgignore`, etc.) if you're concerned about safety, and call the `new DotenvPlugin` with an object that has `path` defined, i.e.,

```js
const DotEnvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');
module.exports = {
/* other settings */
  plugins: [
    // other plugins,
    new DotEnvPlugin({
      path:'.env.local',
      // safe: true, // load '.env.example' to verify the '.env' variables are all set. Can also be a string to a different file.
    })
  ]
}
```

If you do not have a `.env` file, the above `string-replace-webpack-plugin` might be useful, and you just add those variables to your environment. (consult your OS/admin on how to do so)

Lastly, you *can* define them in a command-line call; they just typically need to go before any command issued, i.e. (in bash):

```sh
MY_PARAMETER=some_value node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot
```

Comment: Furthermore, if you can, I add to _my_ dotfiles `PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH` toward the end of the load order, so I can just call the stuff that's installed there _directly_. Both Bash and Zsh seem not to have a problem with it, either. Yes, it's _technically_ a potential vector of attack for malicious scripts, but that's why you sandbox anything unknown, etc. etc.

Comment: I need to be able to add parameters in the command line. So I tried your suggestion and then I try to access parameters inside code by "process" variable. But both args and env properties are empty arrays.

Comment: Well, you can also try using the [`cross-env`](https://npmjs.org/package/cross-env) package and just writing a script in your package file as a debugging method. The above should have worked. If it fails there, your Node.js may be configured strangely.